# About mapping class group.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, open-problem, mapping-class-group

> What is best book for self learning [mapping class group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_class_group)?

I read "A Primer on Mapping Class Groups"
By Benson Farb, Dan Margalit.

Is there a topological space $X$ where we don't know $\mathrm{MCG}(X)$ ?

I want to find some open problem in mapping class group .

Comment: Do you want to focus on mcg of surfaces? Fnding open problems to work on is probably best for an advisor. Also, what do you mean "known", like we don't have a presentation for it?

Comment: @PaulPlummer . Yes . I want focus on $MCG$ . "Known"  , yes exactlly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Primer" is a good source (and so is Ivanov's book) but a bit old. A lot of things are known now that are not there and there are no books covering this information.

As for spaces $X$ such that $MCG(X)$ are not known, relatively little is known about the mapping class groups of 3-manifolds, although see this [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0083830).

There are two famous open problems about MCG of surfaces: whether they can have Kazdan property (T) and whether they can contain [surface subgroups consisting of pseudo-Anosov elements](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/areid/surface_modg.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

Here are some open problems on mapping class groups.

**Question 1:**  Let $S_g$ denote the closed orientable surface of genus $g$.
Is $\text{Mod}(S_g)$ linear?

Bigelow–Budney and Korkmaz were able to prove that $\text{Mod}(S_2)$ is linear. For $g\ge 3$ the conjecture is wide open.

**Question 2:** Is the $k$-th Lawrence representation of $\text{Mod}(S_g)$ faithful for any $k ≥ 1$?

**Question 3:** Is it true that every finite-index subgroup in $\text{Mod}(S_g)$ contains a congruence subgroup?

Comment: This is definitely well outside my area of expertise, but it is weird for me to see a result known about $S_2$, but not for $S_g$ with $g\geq 3$.  Much more common seems to be a distinction between $S_0$, $S_1$, and all the rest.  What makes $S_2$ amenable to such a theorem?  Is $Mod(S_2)$ "smaller" than $Mod(S_g)$ for $g\geq 3$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Every closed Riemann surface of genus 2 has a hyperelliptic involution with 6 fixed points and with quotient homomorphic to the 2-sphere. Using this one can find a very close relation between the genus 2 mapping class group and the 6 strand braid group on the sphere. Then one can exploit the theorem of Bigelow and Kraamer that braid groups are linear.

Comment: @LeeMosher:  Interesting!  Again, as a non-expert in this area, it is still interesting to see $S_2$ behave differently from the other hyperbolic $S_g$s.

Comment: Why question  1 is useful  ? Why this question is important?

Comment: Related to your question 2 (but now for punctured disk rather than a closed genus $ g $ surface), what about the faithfulness of the the 4th Burau representation $ B_4 \to U(4) $? Is that still an open problem?